# Z-ordering in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

Is re-clustering of a z-ordering optimization a manual process in Databricks or is there a process running in the background that asynchronously reorders the cluster index after data has been inserted or updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an asynchronous or continuous process today, but it is an idempotent operation.  From [the docs](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/file-mgmt.html#z-ordering-multi-dimensional-clustering):

> Prior to Databricks Runtime 5.0, Z-Ordering was not an idempotent operation, simply rewriting all data matching the given filter every time the command was run. Starting with Databricks Runtime 5.0, Z-Ordering is idempotent too, just like bin-packing.

You'll have to Z-order new rows in your table, but you won't have to rewrite the entire table to do so.